# How to write Django query expression to convert unix time to datetime?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am writing a function to generate a report from a Django database. My production database is PostgreSQL but my test database is SQLite, so I need to support both.

I need to compare two times, but one is stored in the database as a unix time stamp, and the other is a datetime object. I do not have the freedom to update these models to make this calculation simpler.

Initially I did this calculation in Python but there are a large number of messages and it takes too long, so I set about doing the operations server side.

I have written a custom Django Query expression. I found an online example for PostgreSQL, which works. I can't find the equivalent for SQLite, and I don't have any experience in SQL so I'm finding it tricky to understand what to do from the SQL documentation.

message_delivery__sent is a datetime, base_time_received_s is a float.

What I have so far is this:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F, Func

from .models import Message

class UnixToDatetime(Func):
    template = None
    output_field = models.DateTimeField()

    def as_sqlite(self, compiler, connection, **extra_context):
        self.template = "???"
        return super().as_sql(compiler, connection, **extra_context)

    def as_postgresql(self, compiler, connection):
        self.template = (
            "TO_TIMESTAMP(%(expressions)s)::TIMESTAMP at time zone 'UTC'"
        )
        return super().as_sql(compiler, connection)

def generate_report(*args, **kwargs):
    late_messages = Message.objects.all().annotate(
        latency=F("message_delivery__sent")
        - UnixToDatetime(F("base_time_received_s"))
    ).filter(latency__gt=timedelta(minutes=60))
    ...
```

Can someone please help me determine what the as_sqlite method should be?

Answer (score 0):

I think I just solved it with some trial and error:

```
class UnixToDatetime(Func):
    template = None
    output_field = models.DateTimeField()

    def as_sqlite(self, compiler, connection, **extra_context):
        self.template = "DateTime(%(expressions)s, 'unixepoch')"
        return super().as_sql(compiler, connection, **extra_context)
```